# How to "cast" HashMap<Parent, Double> to HashMap<Child, Double>

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have got this situation:

```java
public abstract class Parent {
    public Parent(){}
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public Child(){
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Child, Double> mapChild = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Parent, Double> mapParent = new HashMap<>();

        foo(mapChild, new Child()); //Wrong 1 arg type
        foo(mapParent, new Child());
    }

    public static void foo(HashMap<Parent, Double> x, Parent parent){
        x.put(parent, 5.0);
    }
}
```

This code does not work, because `foo(mapChild, new Child())` said - "Wrong argument type".
 I tried somethig with Wildcards, but i think it cant work with it. I can create second foo method, but i do not want to duplicate code.

Any ideas?

Comment: PECS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/342852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is

```
public static <T> void foo(Map<T, Double> x, T t) {
  x.put(t, 5.0);
}
```

...not to *actually* put a `Parent` object in a `Map<Child, Double>`.

Comment: even better would be `Map<? super T, Double>`.

Comment: @Turing85: nah.  They're equivalent, for this use case; `T` will get lifted to the appropriate type.

Comment: true that. Took me a while to convince myself, but it seems that `extends` and `super` to a generic parameter is superfluous.

Comment: Would it be correct / useful to  have T `extends Parent` like this: `public static <T extends Parent> void foo(...)`?

Comment: You _could,_ but why bother adding the constraint when none of the logic actually cares?

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I used @AlexandreDupriez version, because my method needs it. Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use

> `<? extends Parent>`

in your collection. So the collection can accept both Child and Parent.

Comment: That is actually the wrong approach. It would be better to make the method `foo(...)` generic in the second parameter (`parent`) and set the `Map` to `<? super T>` (where `T` is the type of the second argument).

Comment: He said any idea. It was mine. Just so you know your comment would have been much better without the first sentence. We are all here sharing ideas. With different level and skills. I didn’t think about the accepted solution. I am glad other did.